# Read from file in Prolog

Tags: prolog

i ve  used 'read' to read the stream, however, when i invoke
`read_input('myFile.txt', N, K, B, Steps, Broken)` my interpreter answers false. 
here is my code:

```
read_input('myFile.txt', N, K, B, Steps, Broken) :-
    open('myFile.txt', read, Stream),
    read_line(Stream, [N, K, B]),
    read_line(Stream, Steps),
    read_line(Stream, Broken).

    /*
     * An auxiliary predicate that reads a line and returns the list of
     * integers that the line contains.
     */  
read_line(Stream, List) :-
    read_line_to_codes(Stream, Line),
    ( Line = [] -> List = []
    ; atom_codes(A, Line),
      atomic_list_concat(As, ' ', A),
      maplist(atom_number, As, List)
    ).
```

Comment: Why is your `read_input/6` defined with `'myFile.txt'` as the first argument? Why does your first `read_line/2` call pass a list as the second argument? The predicate expects a single variable for the second argument if you're expecting to read a line from the file.

Comment: yeah you were right! thanks

Comment: Your predicate should read, `read_input(FileName, N, K, B, Steps, Broken) :-
    open(FileName, read, Stream), ...`